# Unexpected white space in formatted output

Tags: java, format, output

Task: print a table of square and cube values. 
Expected output:

```
number  square  cube
4       16      64  
5       25      125  
6       36      216  
7       49      343  
8       64      512  
9       81      729  
10      100     1000
```

Using System.out.printf, I've made a table almost similar to the expected output, however there is an excess whitespace in a cube column.

```
int a,b;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
a = input.nextInt();
b = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("number  square  cube");
while(a<=b) {
    System.out.printf("%d %8d %8d  \n", a, a*a, a*a*a);
    a++;
}
```

My output:

```
number  square  cube
4       16       64  
5       25      125  
6       36      216  
7       49      343  
8       64      512  
9       81      729  
10      100     1000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
System.out.printf("%d %8d %8d  \n", a, a*a, a*a*a);
```

to

```
System.out.printf("%-7d %-7d %-7d\n", a, a*a, a*a*a);
```

with no other changes, for the range 4 to 10, I get

```
number  square  cube
4       16      64     
5       25      125    
6       36      216    
7       49      343    
8       64      512    
9       81      729    
10      100     1000
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I expect to be an output! Could you please explain what does - symbol mean?

Comment: Align text of digits on the left of a seven space field (`%-7d`).